# URL Forward all links from domain without slugs

Tags: domains, web-hosting, url, domain-registrar

I have an old site which I no longer use so I decided to redirect the domain to an article from another domain. The old site does not have web hosting anymore which means I had to url forward through my domain registrar (Namecheap) to redirect.

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/385/77/how-do-i-set-up-url-forwarding-for-a-domain) and succesfully redirected all traffic from

`http://old-site.com` to `http://new-site.com/post/2`


But when I try to access `http://old-site.com/old-slug/dead-link` it redirects to 
`http://new-site.com/post/2/old-slug/dead-link`

Is there a way to redirect all urls from `http://old-site.com`, regardless of slugs, to  `http://new-site.com/post/2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ask Namecheap support if you can set up the forwarding that way with their service.

If they cannot do that, then you have to make the redirect with your own web server.